# Problem in selecting first-child in CSS | VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors

First, here's the structure of my VueJS app so far:

```
App
 |__ StepBar
          |__ StepUnit
```

Here is how it currently looks like:
[image]

Basically, the StepBar component is an `ul` element that contains three StepUnit elements, where each one of them is a `li` element that contains a `span`. I added two pseudo-elements to the `span` element: `:before`, which represents the circled number above the text, and `:after`, which represents the horizontal line on the top left of the StepUnit component. Now, I'm trying to delete the horizontal line of the first StepUnit component by doing:

```
.step-unit span:first-child:after {
  content: none;
 }
```

but I can't make it work. Do you have any idea why?

Here's the code of the StepBar component:

```
<template>
    <ul class="step-bar">
        <StepUnit name="Dati dell'immobile"/>
        <StepUnit name="Privato/Agente"/>
        <StepUnit name="Report"/>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
import StepUnit from './StepUnit';

export default {
    name: 'StepBar',
    components: {
        StepUnit
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .step-bar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 20px 60px 60px;
        padding: 0;
        counter-reset: step;
    }
</style>
```

And here's the code of the StepUnit component:

```
<template>
    <li class="step-unit">
        <span>{{ name }}</span>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'StepUnit',
    props: {
        name: String,
        img: String
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .step-unit {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    .step-unit span {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #BBBBBB;
    }

    .step-unit span:before {
        display: flex;
        place-self: center;
        place-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        content: counter(step);
        counter-increment: step;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .step-unit span:after {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #BBBBBB;
        margin-top: -40px;
        margin-left: -50%;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .step-unit span:first-child:after {
        content: none;
    }

</style>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `.step-unit:first-child span:after`

Comment: Wow! I didn't manage to think of it, thank you @TemaniAfif :)